# How to iterate through 2d array to split the inner array in java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have the following 2d array:

```
[[Reflux Symptom Sensitivity Index (Impedance)], [Symptom       Acid    Nonacid All Reflux], [Regurgitate       34% 71% 36%], [Stomach pain     21% 14% 19%], [Chest pain       3%  0%  3%], [], [Reflux Symptom Association Probability (Impedance)]]
```

I would like to all the inner arrays apart from the first one, by whitespace so that  I end up with:

```
[[Reflux Symptom Sensitivity Index (Impedance)], [Symptom,Acid, Nonacid, All, Reflux], [Symptom,Acid, Nonacid, All, Reflux], [Symptom,Acid, Nonacid, All, Reflux],[Chest pain,3%,0%,3%]]
```

I could write the following code:

```
ArrayList<List<String>> Arr_RSI_table2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> stats = Arr_RSI_table2d.get(1);
                // remove() returns the object that was removed
                String allStats = stats.remove(0);
                String allStats2=allStats.trim();
                Collections.addAll(stats, allStats2.split("\\s"));
                List<String> Arr_RSI_table2d_col2 = Arr_RSI_table2d.get(2);
                // remove() returns the object that was removed
                String All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col2 = Arr_RSI_table2d_col2.remove(0);
                String All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col2_2=allStats.trim();
                Collections.addAll(Arr_RSI_table2d_col2, All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col2_2.split("\\s"));

                List<String> Arr_RSI_table2d_col3 = Arr_RSI_table2d.get(3);
                // remove() returns the object that was removed
                String All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col3 = Arr_RSI_table2d_col3.remove(0);
                String All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col3_2=allStats.trim();
                Collections.addAll(Arr_RSI_table2d_col3, All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col3_2.split("\\s"));

                List<String> Arr_RSI_table2d_col4 = Arr_RSI_table2d.get(4);
                // remove() returns the object that was removed
                String All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col4 = Arr_RSI_table2d_col4.remove(0);
                String All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col4_2=allStats.trim();
                Collections.addAll(Arr_RSI_table2d_col4, All_Arr_RSI_table2d_col4_2.split("\\s"));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is?...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
 String[] innerArray = myArray.get(i);
 for (int j = 0; j < innerArray.length; j++) {
  innerArray[j] = removeWhiteSpace(innerArray[j]);
 }
}
```

You will need a helper method to remove white space:

```
private String removeWhiteSpace(String toTrim) {
 String toRet = "";
 String trimSplit[] = toTrim.split(" ");
 for (String word : trimSplit) {
  if (!word.trim().isEmpty()) {
   toRet = toRet + word + " ";
  }
 }
 return toRet.trim();
}
```

This is untested but it should work fine. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: The outer array is an ArrayList though. Sorry- edited code to show this

Comment: @SebastianZeki No problem - give me a sec and I'll edit.

Comment: @SebastianZeki There you go - edited it to account for the outer being an array list. Let me know if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<List<String>>  myList = new ArrayList();
    void loopThroghArray() {

        for (List<String> list : myList) {
                //outer loop


            for (String string : list) {
                //inner loop
            }

        }

    }
```

its hard to understand your code , since you have not given even the type of your array bt here i have made a example on looping through 2dimensional array. im using a enhanced for loop to loop the first array and another enhanced for loop to iterate the 2nd array you can do the spliting inside the 2nd for loop . you might wanna try this.

Comment: Thanks. I have amended the code. The structure is of ArrayList<List<String>> How can I exclude the first element from the outer loop